Calculate $s₂(y)$
I have a number of the form $$y=2×(2^{k+1}-1)×(2^{k}-1)×2^{m}$$ where $k,m$ are positive integers. Let $s₂$ denotes the the binary sum-of-digits function. Then my question is how calculate $s₂(y)$. I know that $s₂(2^{m})=1$ and $s₂(2^{k}-1)=k$
Solution:
By a comment below:
$$s₂(y)=s₂((2^{k+1}-1)×(2^{k}-1))$$
For $k=1$, we have $s₂(y)=2$ and for $k=2$, we have $s₂(y)=3$. Several other values show that $s₂(y)=k+1$. However, I cannot show further results.

What is the binary sum of digits function?  The number of $1's$ in the binary representation?

@lulu: Yes. it is the number of $1$.

Fundamental hint: Try values of $k$ and look for patterns. Make a conjecture and then try to prove it. (I can give more hints after you show some effort on the problem)

See Hamming Weight

At least you should see that the factors $2$ and $2^m$ (why not write just $2^{m+1}$?) don't count because they contribute only to the trailing zeros in binary.

Simplify.  Note $2\times a$ has the same number of $1$ digits as $a$.  Therefore, the $2 \times$ and the $\times 2^m$ can be omitted for computation of $s_2$.

@Milten: I show some of my attempts to solve the exercice.

@Milten: From your answer I conclud that $$s₂((2ⁿ-1)-(2^{m}-1))=n-m$$  Is that true!

@Milten: Or more generally, $$s₂( 2^{r}×(2ⁿ-1)-2^{k}×(2^{m}-1))=n-m$$

@Safwane Your first comment is true, provided $n\ge m$. Your second comment is false. But it would have been true to say $s_2(2^k[(2^n-1)-(2^m-1)]) = n-m$ for $n\ge m$. You can also salvage your second comment by requiring $r\le k\le n-m$ (or maybe something close to that). It's about making sure that you are never subtracting a $1$ from a $0$.

Hint:
You already noted that we can disregard the even factors. For the odd ones, see how the numbers $(2^{k+1}-1)(2^k-1)$ look in binary, starting at $k=1$:
$$
11, 10101, 1101001, 111010001, 11110100001, ...
$$
If you can find and formalize the pattern here (it's easiest to look at the larger values of $k$), and show that it holds for all $k$, you will have showed that the answer is $k+1$. The easiest way to do this is to write the numbers above as a sum/difference of numbers of the form $2^a$ or $2^a-1$. For example, $1111000$ can be written as $(2^7-1) - (2^3-1)$, and in this imagined scenario we might have in general (here I'm assuming a very simple pattern of course): $s_2((2^{k+4}-1) - (2^k-1)) = (k+4) - k = 4$.
Try to adapt such a line of reasoning to your situation. When you have come up with the sum/difference expression giving the pattern, you should do two things: Show that it is equal to $(2^{k+1}-1)(2^k-1)$ (by simple algebra), and count the number of resulting $1$'s, similarly to how I did above.
Give it a go, and I'll help further if you are stuck again.
